# Can't change height/width of <div>

Tags: css, html

I'm learning HTML/CSS and decided to try this:

```
<p>A paragraph with no margins specified.</p>
<div style="width=300px; height=300px; background-color:yellow;><p>This paragraph is in a divider.</p></div>
<p>A paragraph with no margins specified.</p>
```

After some googling, I found that you can't change width/height for inline elements. So I tried making both the `<div>` and `<p>` into block elements using `display:block`, but that didn't change anything. The width goes on infinitely off-screen, and the height is only as high as the `<p>` is. 
I want there to be a `<p>` in a 300x300 `<div>`, so how can I do this? Also, why doesn't any of these ways work (even when I change to `display:block`)?
Thanks.

Also, I know you shouldn't use excessive CSS like I did. This is only because I was testing stuff with W3's "Try-It-Yourself" HTML editor.

Comment: = sign is invalid in CSS for key value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Errors in your code:

```
<div style="width=300px; height=300px; background-color:yellow;>
-----------------^-------------^-------------------------------^
                  Replace with :                               Missing "
```

---

You are giving it wrong. Replace `=` with `:`, and you missed a `"`:

```
<div style="width:300px; height:300px; background-color:yellow;">
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `div` and `p` are block elements by default, so you do not need to specify `display:block;` for them. You are using old-school html attribute name/value setting (name = value) inside your style attribute.

You'll want to use CSS properties inside the style attribute that look like `name:value;`.

```
style="width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#FFFF00;"
```

You might want to take a look at some of the resources at Team Treehouse: http://teamtreehouse.com/library/websites/build-a-simple-website/website-basics

or Code School: http://www.codeschool.com/paths/html-css

Hope this helps you continue learning.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using "max-width" instead of just "width."